# Simultaneously run grouped animations jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I would like the first block of animations to be executed first simultaneously, followed by the second block of code executed simultaneously. Thanks in advance

```
$('#logo').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 2000});
$('#logo').animate({ width: "300px" }, 2000);
$('#logo_img').animate({ width: "300px" }, 2000);

$('#logo').delay(500).animate({marginTop: "-500px", width: "200px"}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});
$("#logo_img").animte({width: "200px"},1000);
```

Comment: Have you checked out CSS keyframe animations? It would seem a much better solution to your requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually *all* of the jquery animations accept callbacks so you could animate the first 3 synchronously and then have the last 3 embedded in a callback something like this:

```
$('#logo').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 2000});
$('#logo').animate({ width: "300px" }, 2000);
$('#logo_img').animate({ width: "300px" }, 2000, function() {
    $('#logo').delay(500).animate({marginTop: "-500px", width: "200px"}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});
    $("#logo_img").animte({width: "200px"},1000);
});
```

I hope this helps to answer your question.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `animate` has a complete callback where you can chain followup functions, eg.

```
$( "#logo" ).animate({
    width: "300px"
}, 2000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help but I've just spotted my mistake, my syntax was incorrect on the 5th line; instead of "animate" I wrote "animte". Easy mistake but your answers still helped me solve it so thank you